# Array Reduce Sum Using Recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, sum, reduce

Given an array of length n, consolidate the sum created by adding index pairs until there's only a single index.

EXAMPLES:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] => 48

Explanation:

- The next array would be [3, 5, 7, 9] because [1+2, 2+3, 3+4, 4+5]
- The next array would be [8, 12, 16] because [3+5, 5+7, 7+9]
- The next array would be [20, 28] because [8+12, 12+16]
- The final answer would be [48] because [20+28] and there are not enough operands to add

This is the solution I came up with but I feel like there's a simpler way to achieve the same solution. I'm trying to understand recursion but I need some explanation on why when we call our stacks, we do it from the (n - 1) or from the (n + 1) to reach our base cases and how do we know which one to use? I don't understand why we're using those passing arguments when we are returning our helper function.

```js
function reduceSum(input) {
  function simplify(input, index) {
    if (index === 1) {
      return input[0];
    }

    if (index === 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      input[i] += input[i + 1];
    }

    return simplify(input, index - 1);
  }

  return simplify(input, input.length);
}


console.log(reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 20)
console.log(reduceSum([5]) == 5)
console.log(reduceSum([]) == 0)
console.log(reduceSum([1, 3, 5]) == 12)
console.log(reduceSum([-5, 5]) == 0)
console.log(reduceSum([-5, 5, -5, 5]) == 0)
console.log(reduceSum([-5, 5, 5, -5]) == 20)
```

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: Sorry, javascript.

Comment: An advice would be to just run the last array `[-5, 5, 5, -5]` and then do a `console.log(input)` after the for loop to see what happens to `input`. For each recursive loop, the last index will be NaN, hence why the code is calling `simplify(input, index - 1)`. Tbh, this solution is much shorter than I would had come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the following is a genuinely simpler way to achieve the solution as it does basically the same thing (although it does not modify the original array), but perhaps there's something useful here:

```js
function reduceSum(input) {
  if(input.length <= 1)
    return input[0] || 0;
  
  return reduceSum(
    input.reduce(
      (acc, val, i, { [i + 1]: next }) =>
        typeof next !== 'undefined' ? [ ...acc, val + next ] : acc,
      []
    )
  );
}


console.log(reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 20)
console.log(reduceSum([5]) == 5)
console.log(reduceSum([]) == 0)
console.log(reduceSum([1, 3, 5]) == 12)
console.log(reduceSum([-5, 5]) == 0)
console.log(reduceSum([-5, 5, -5, 5]) == 0)
console.log(reduceSum([-5, 5, 5, -5]) == 20)
```

The `next` variable is populated using object destructuring on the array argument passed to the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) callback function. It will be undefined when the reduce method processes the last element of the array, this last element gets skipped; this means that each time we run `reduceSum` the array gets shorter by one element (as per your original).

Comment: You can more than double the speed of your method by not using spread, destructuring and using `i` to detect last item: `(acc, val, i, next) => (i < next.length - 1 && (acc[i] = val + next[++i]),  acc)`

Comment: This is very useful to have to perform the task in-place. Thank you for sharing this with me!

Comment: Thank you @vanowm, that's some food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

Each loop updates values in the array. And with each loop the index needs to be reduced, otherwise it will be infinite loop. Just add `console.log("" + input)` right after the `for` loop and you'll see how `input` progresses with each call of `simplify()` function.

There are a few optimizations can be done to your code:

1. you don't need `simplify()` at all, simply check if `index` variable is `undefined`:

```js
function reduceSum(input, index) {
  if (index === undefined)
    index = input.length;

  if (index === 1) {
    return input[0];
  }

  if (index === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i] += input[i + 1];
  }
  console.log("input:  " + input);
  return reduceSum(input, index - 1);
}

console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == 48)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 20)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([5]) == 5)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 3, 5]) == 12)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5, -5, 5]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5, 5, -5]) == 20)
```

2. You can also optimize a little by only looping through 0 to `index - 1` instead of entire array:

```js
function reduceSum(input, index) {
  if (index === undefined)
    index = input.length;

  if (index === 1) {
    return input[0];
  }

  if (index === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
    input[i] += input[i + 1];
  }
  console.log("input: " + input);
  return reduceSum(input, index - 1);
}

console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == 48)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 20)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([5]) == 5)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 3, 5]) == 12)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5, -5, 5]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5, 5, -5]) == 20)
```

3. Further you can optimize the code by adding default value to the `index` variable and moving conditions to the end the function, this way it won't need an extra call of the function to get final result:

```js
function reduceSum(input, index = input.length - 1) {
  for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    input[i] += input[i + 1];
  }
  console.log("input: " + input);
  if (index > 1)
    return reduceSum(input, --index);

  //return final result or 0 if array is empty
  return input[0] || 0;
}

console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == 48)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 20)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([5]) == 5)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 3, 5]) == 12)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5, -5, 5]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5, 5, -5]) == 20)
```

4. Finally, you can get rid of `index` all together, by removing last item from the `input` array instead, this method is slower than the above though:

```js
function reduceSum(input) {
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
    input[i] += input[i + 1];
  }
  console.log("input: " + input);
  if (input.length > 1)
  {
    //remove last item by reducing length of the array
    input.length--;
    return reduceSum(input);
  }
  //return final result or 0 if array is empty
  return input[0] || 0;
}

console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == 48)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 20)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([5]) == 5)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([1, 3, 5]) == 12)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5, -5, 5]) == 0)
console.log("result:", reduceSum([-5, 5, 5, -5]) == 20)
```

Comment: Ahhhh thank you so much for breaking that down so well for me! I think I finally understand it now. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop as follows:

```js
function reduceSum(input) {
  if( input.length < 2 ) {
    return input[0] || 0;
  }
  const arr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
    arr.push(input[i] + input[i+1]);
  }
  return reduceSum( arr );
}


console.log(reduceSum([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 20)
console.log(reduceSum([5]) == 5)
console.log(reduceSum([]) == 0)
console.log(reduceSum([1, 3, 5]) == 12)
console.log(reduceSum([-5, 5]) == 0)
console.log(reduceSum([-5, 5, -5, 5]) == 0)
console.log(reduceSum([-5, 5, 5, -5]) == 20)
```